# display:block при нажатии на radio

Tags: html, css

Нужно, чтобы при наведении или нажатии на radio

`.open2 img {display: none;}` менялся на `{display: block;}`

```
<div id='apple_iphone' class='gadget_open'>
    <div class='open1'>
        <input type='radio' id='iphone_4' name='iphone_model' value='4'>
        <label for='iphone_4'>4</label>
    </div>

    <div class='open2'>
        <img src='img/iphone.jpg' alt=''>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.open2 img {display: none;}
```

Comment: Можно сделать на css, если изображение будет рядом с label или на js

Comment: я знаю, что можно на css сделать, и без js... но не силен в селекторах. Там будет что-то наподобии #apple_iphone label[for=iphone_4]:checked ~ .open2 img{
 display:block;
}

Comment: Хочешь написать на js?

Comment: Хочу наоборот без использования js

Comment: т.к. `css` работает каскадно, то бишь проходит по селекторам вглубь, то надо, чтобы обрабатываемые блоки были соседями одного парента

Comment: на js это 1 строчка

Answer (score 3, accepted):

пример с js

```js
document.querySelector('.open1 input').onmouseenter = function() {
  document.querySelector('.open2 img').style = 'display: block';
}

document.querySelector('.open1 input').onmouseleave = function() {
  document.querySelector('.open2 img').style = 'display: none';
}
```

```css
.open2 img {display: none;}
```

```html
<div id="apple_iphone" class="gadget_open">
  
  <div class="open1">
    <input type="radio" id="iphone_4" name="iphone_model" value="4" />
    <label for="iphone_4">4</label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="open2">
    <img src="img/iphone.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  
</div>
```

пример с css (mini hack)

```css
.open2 img {display: none;}
.open1 {display: block;}
.open1:hover + .open2 img {display: block;}
```

```html
<div id="apple_iphone" class="gadget_open">
  
  <div class="open1">
    <input type="radio" id="iphone_4" name="iphone_model" value="4" />
    <label for="iphone_4">4</label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="open2">
    <img src="img/iphone.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Если только так

Comment: Это хак как бы, т. к. проверка идёт через соседа, а не более вложенного потомка.

Comment: такой вариант не подойдет, ибо кнопок будет больше чем одна.

Comment: если не затруднит, подскажите пожалуйста вариант на js

Comment: @f1amestar, щя...

Comment: @Doofy, а возможно с указанием id или имени input? (кнопок будет несколько)

Comment: @f1amestar, конечно, в `querySelector('.open1 input')` вместо `input` пишешь `#input1` для `id='input1'` или для класса вместо шарпа точка

Comment: @Doofy, Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 3):

Не выйдет чисто на `CSS`.
Для получения значения `#iphone_4`, нужно зайти глубже, чем потомок с картинкой.
В `CSS` нету селектора `выше по древу`, так что выше не подняться.

Answer (score 3):

Т.к. `CSS`, в отличиие от `JS`, не может подняться вверх под DOM, то возможны два варианта:

- размещать эти блоки рядом и использовать "соседние селекторы":

```css
img {
  display: none;
}
input:hover ~ img {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id='apple_iphone' class='gadget_open'>
  <div class='open1'>
    <input type='radio' id='iphone_4' name='iphone_model' value='4'>
    <label for='iphone_4'>4</label>
    <img src='img/iphone.jpg' alt=''>
  </div>
</div>
```

- использовать `:hover` не целевого элемента, а его родителя:

```css
.open2 img {
  display: none;
}
.open1:hover + .open2 img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id='apple_iphone' class='gadget_open'>
  <div class='open1'>
    <input type='radio' id='iphone_4' name='iphone_model' value='4'>
    <label for='iphone_4'>4</label>
  </div>
  <div class='open2'>
    <img src='img/iphone.jpg' alt=''>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Если всё же интересует вариант с JS:

- активацию радио можно обработать вот так:

```js
document.querySelector('.open1 input').onchange = function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    document.querySelector('.open2 img').style.display = 'block'
  }
}
```

```css
.open2 img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id='apple_iphone' class='gadget_open'>
  <div class='open1'>
    <input type='radio' id='iphone_4' name='iphone_model' value='4'>
    <label for='iphone_4'>4</label>
  </div>
  <div class='open2'>
    <img src='img/iphone.jpg' alt=''>
  </div>
</div>
```

- наведение вот так:

```js
document.querySelector('.open1 input').onmouseenter = function() {
  document.querySelector('.open2 img').style.display = 'block'
}
document.querySelector('.open1 input').onmouseout = function() {
  document.querySelector('.open2 img').style.display = 'none'
}
```

```css
.open2 img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id='apple_iphone' class='gadget_open'>
  <div class='open1'>
    <input type='radio' id='iphone_4' name='iphone_model' value='4'>
    <label for='iphone_4'>4</label>
  </div>
  <div class='open2'>
    <img src='img/iphone.jpg' alt=''>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А как в 1ом варианте сделать так, чтобы при смене чека на другой input пропадала картинка?

Comment: в первом Css или Js ?

Comment: в js варианте....